# Как хранить несколько List<T> и передавать

Tags: c#, массивы, list

Есть список листов, которые планирую заполнять из БД. Как их можно сохранить в 1 список?

Хотел сделать `List< List< T >>`, но нельзя - разные структуры.

Хотелось бы получить что-то наподобие:

```
List[0]< List<systeam>-200строк List<etlcontrolload>-50строк List<sem>-10строк >

List[1]< List<systeam>-220строк List<etlcontrolload>-55строк List<sem>-15строк >
```

---

```
List<systeam> SysteamList = new List<systeam>();
List<etlcontrolload> EtlcontrolloadList = new List<etlcontrolload>();
List<sem> SemList = new List<sem>();
List<ddmpkgstate> DdmpkgstateList = new List<ddmpkgstate>();
List<etlcontroltable> EtlcontroltableList = new List<etlcontroltable>();
List<dqlog> DqlogList = new List<dqlog>();
List<etlcontrolloadarch> EtlcontrolloadarchList = new List<etlcontrolloadarch>();
```

Comment: Создание классов-помоек плохая практика,но раз уж если это жизненно необходимо - создайте класс, полями которого являются ваши листы, выгружаемые из БД и заполняйте их через свойства. После заполнения всех полей добавляйте этот объект класса-помойки в List<T>, где T - класс-помойка.

Comment: То есть правильнее было был для каждой таблицы из бд создать свой отдельный класс и в них хранить данные? Просто немного не понятно как потом эти данные отделять если я делаю следующий запрос то в этом классе будут данные как от 1ого запроса так и от 2ого

Comment: @Exodium в идеале бы если вы знаете годный пример с нормальной структурой как загружать данные с бд то не могли бы вы скинуть?

Comment: В схожей ситуации я использовал 'Dictionary <string, List<T>>' Вместо string может быть любой тип ключа.

Comment: @foxhound топикастер пытается изобрести то ли контекст, то ли модель. у него явно фиксированное количество типов. зачем ему dictionary? чтобы потом при каждом обращении кастовать? :)

Comment: @220VOLT годный пример с нормальной структурой - возьмите любой орм, как вам iluxa1810 посоветовал ниже - хотя бы Entity Framework, и работайте через него.

Comment: @Exodium: «Класс-помойка» — крепко сказано. Запомню и буду употреблять.

Comment: Вообщем вы какие то сложные варианты предлагаете для хайлвл программистов на не для простых на уровне if(w>5) return true else return false. Сделал как @Exodium написал класс помойку который содержит все эти листы и его добавляю в лист.

Answer (score 2):

Если ты разрабатываешь независимый проект без тонны исторического кода, рекомендую сразу взять на вооружение тонкий фреймворк для работы с базой, а не изобретать собственный велосипед. Например, [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db).

Поддерживает большинство популярных баз данных, есть примеры на все случаи жизни. Минимальный оверхед на выполнение запросов.

И, естественно, никаких `List<List<List>>` в продукте быть не должно.
Но если очень хочется, тебе ничто не мешает написать обёртку над списком и спрятать под общий интерфейс или просто хранить их в списке `List<object>`. Но это очень хреновое решение.

Answer (score -2):

В идеале, каждая сущность должна иметь свой собственный класс с полями. В свою очередь должна быть еще сущность(Например, DataBase), которая агрегирует в себе эти сущности и хранит соединение.

Примерно, по такому принципу работают современные ORM.
Если вам нужно выполнять сложные запросы, а не просто получать данные, то я бы на вашем месте взял бы какую-нибудь ORM и не изобретал велосипед.

По идее, если вы сделаете `List<Object>`, то сможете все что угодно хранить там, но вы потеряете безопасность типов...

Поэтому, лучше сделать, как я написал в начале. И безопасность типов будет на месте, и код будет более читаем.

Comment: Мне нужно просто получать данные, без сложных запросов. У меня есть таблица в ней условно 100к записей не надо каждый раз выбирать все строки а только по условию там 200 строк вот я их выбрал они у меня в листе дальше из следующей таблицы с 20к строк выбираю 10 и т.д. Хотел получить List[0]< 200строк, 20строк, 50строк > | List[1] < 195строк, 21строк, 55строк > Я так понял это не очень правильно, и я не могу понять тогда как сущность(Например, DataBase) их может агрегировать.

Comment: @220VOLT будете работать с нормальной строгой типизацией. `database.Sems` - все sem-ы. `database.DQLogs` - все логи. `database.DQLogs.Take(20)` - первые 20 логов, `database.DQLogs.Where(l => l.SomeField > 10)` - логи по условию. C# - строго типизированный язык. Если вам нужно хранить несколько (заранее известное фиксированное количество) коллекций объектов разных типов - делаете класс со свойствами для каждой коллекции.

Comment: Не понимаю, за что меня так яростно заминусовали... Вроде, все по делу сказал.